# "ip route get 8.8.8.8" equivalent in Mac?

Tags: mac, network, macos

In Linux, I use `ip route get 8.8.8.8` to determine the route and interface to connect to IP 8.8.8.8.

Since iproute2 is unavailable on Mac, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply use the `route(8)` command

```
$ route get 8.8.8.8
   route to: dns.google
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: 192.168.0.1
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0
```

The `ip` tool is not supported on MacOS because it's a very Linux-specific implementation (Netlink). The Mac version of `route` uses another interface (see `man 4 route`).